# Will Angels still not enter a home if there are pictures of animate objects in cupboards, drawers or boxes?

Tags: malaikah

Will Angels still not enter a home if there are pictures of animate objects in cupboards, drawers or boxes?

Comment: It is important to state what kind of angels are being referred to here as we know that the two angels assigned to each individual who record their every deed always remain with them till death. We can't just put statues/photos in our houses and do bad deeds expecting they will not be recorded by the angels ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angels are absent wherever there is a personification or a drawing of a creature (with a soul) like humans, or animals, etc.

Source: **Hadith -Bukhari 4:47, Narrated 'Aisha** ([sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/35))

> I stuffed for the Prophet a pillow decorated with pictures (of
>   animals) which looked like a Namruqa (i.e. a small cushion). He came
>   and stood among the people with excitement apparent on his face. I
>   said, "O Allah's Apostle! What is wrong?" He said, "What is this
>   pillow?" I said, "I have prepared this pillow for you, so that you may
>   recline on it." He said, "Don't you know that angels do not enter a
>   house wherein there are pictures; and whoever makes a picture will be
>   punished on the Day of Resurrection and will be asked to give life to
>   (what he has created)?"

Comment: It would be good to elaborate your answer as it needs more meat to be helpful! As you only quote a hadith and maybe there are some opinion or comments on it which may give a clear view or meaning of it!

Comment: @Medi1Saif : The Hadith is from `Bukhari` book which is contains "correct" hadiths. You can't do any comments. It's the basis. If you doubt it, you're doubting a fundemental pilar of Sunnah, and this of Islam.

Comment: First you didn't understand my statement our view in this site is that references don't speak for themselves second al-Bukhari is not infallible so questioning is allowed.

Comment: I didn't say you're not allowed to ask the question. Re-read. When you read an article in Wikipedia and you got a UN report as a source, do you question the UN report ? ;) That was my point.

Comment: Please read http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/do-evidences-speak-for-themselves